# Moving files to different directories based on key in dictionary

Tags: file, dictionary, file-transfer

I am new to this, please tell me if the form is not correct.

I am trying to move my images from a file to a new empty files based on their name related to their key in the dictionary I created. Basically their label.

The dictionary is of this form:

```
print(multivalue_dict)

defaultdict(list,{'cat_a': ['55b85ea15a1536d46b7190ad6fff8ce7.jpg',
'd4684dcdc759dd9cdf41504698d737d8.jpg',
'6325b6870c54cd47be6ebfbffa620ec7.jpg'],
'cat_b': ['55b85ea15a1536d46b7190ad6fff8ce7.jpg',
'd4684dcdc759dd9cdf41504698d737d8.jpg',
'6325b6870c54cd47be6ebfbffa620ec7.jpg'],....}
```

The desired outcome would be then to have a file cat_a with all the images inside.
I am trying use the path and shutil

```
import os
import shutil

source_dir = "/Users/Me/Downloads/File/Images"
for key in multivalue_dict:
    target_dir = f"/Users/Me/Downloads/File/{key}"
    for file in multivalue_dict[key]:
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), target_dir)
```

Though, I get the error:

---

Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/gs/0bx6d0ms3jxfgjd6vfkz22l40000gn/T/ipykernel_29606/1312100907.py in 
7         if os.path.exists(file):
8             pass
----> 9         shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), target_dir)

/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/shutil.py in move(src, dst, copy_function)
821
822         if os.path.exists(real_dst):
--> 823             raise Error("Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst)
824     try:
825         os.rename(src, real_dst)

Error: Destination path '/Users/Me/Downloads/File/cat_a/f54d0c5cbd8e2270742293edf9075cb1.jpg' already exists

It seems that it is able to transfer 1 image to a new file but then stop, because it loops over it again.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution using `iterrows()` and `pathlib` rather than `dictionary` and `shutil`.

```
from pathlib import Path

for (index,row) in df.iterrows():
    for label in label_list:
        if row.product_cat == label:
            p = Path(f'/Users/Me/Downloads/Images/{row.image}')
            
p.rename(Path(f'/Users/Me/Downloads/Images/{label}/{row.image}'))
```